# HttpSession Junit Testing

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4

I can't do mock on HttpSession. Method for testing looks like this:

```
@GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/feed")
    public String feed(HttpSession session, Model model) throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (session.getAttribute("loginStatus") == null) throw new UnauthorizedException("You have to login first");
        Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");
        model.addAttribute("posts", postService.feed(userId));
        return "posts/feed";
    }
```

And the test looks like this:

```
 @Mock
    private PostService postService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private PostViewController controller;

    @Mock
    private HttpSession session;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        controller = new PostViewController(postService);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void feed() throws Exception {
        when(session.getAttribute("loginStatus")).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/feed"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("posts/feed"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("posts"));
    }
```

I always get UnauthorizedException, but I need to avoid it. How can I add some parameters for session to simulate work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the related session methods to configure the session state during configuring the `MockHttpServlet` .Internally , it will create a `MockHttpSession` for the `MockHttpServlet` you are building.

```java
 mockMvc.perform(get("/feed")
           .sessionAttr("loginStatus", true)
           .sessionAttr("userId", 1234l))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("posts/feed"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("posts"));
```